# Giving right margin in button on being clicked in android

Tags: android

I have a screen where I display five buttons inside a Linearlayout vertically.
this linear layout is inside a relative layout and aligned to parent right.
Now I need that when any button is clicked it should shift leftwards while others remain at the original position.
I am trying to give left margin to the button on being clicked but the problem is all the buttons are shifting and not only that one.

Here is the code

```
 final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;

    mColorButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fillDataList(1);
            mIsClicked = true;
            //[start] setting the colour of button
                    mColorButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_stick) ;
                mColorButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    mPatternButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_stick);
                    mDistributionButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_stick);
                    mShapeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_stick);
                    mLesionButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown_stick);
            //[end] setting the colour of button
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is the problem:

By default all Buttons are left aligned and when you give right margin to a `Button` it expands its parent layout size. The parent expands it self with its child. So all the `Button` shifted left side.

try to give `android:layout_gravity="right"` to all `Button` in XML or code.

Comment: your logic is absolutely right. the parent does expand itself. But the  solution that u provided doesn't work

Comment: are you giving gravity in XML or in java..?